# provider with invariant name 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, devart

I get this error message when using my API with PostGres database.

"The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details."

I have the feeling I need to install Devart product on my staging and production server to fix the error. Is it right? In case this is right I would like to understand why simply copying or publishing Devart dll is not enough? Normally it should be enough.

In error message I can read "is either not registered". What does it mean to be registered? Is it rehgistered in confi file or I need to do a specific operation on my staging and produciton machine?

[image]

Comment: The Devart.Data.PostgreSql.dll is in my bin of my website on IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register configuration information in the DbProviderFactories section of the *.config file:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" />
    <add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version=7.12.1328.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Replace 7.12.1328.0 here with your actual version.

Refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?deployment.html.